# limit access to a web folder based on subdomain

Tags: php, apache

I have a folder off my webroot that is linked to a subdomain. The folder can be accessed from either sub.domain.com or domain.com/sub ... I want to limit access ONLY to people accessing it from the subdomain. I'm currently doing this in php on the index page but I'm sure theres a better way. Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have move that directory outside the `domain.com` folders. 
Then you point your `sub.domain.com` virtual host to this new directory.

Maybe you can also use the rewrite engine to redirect `domain.com/sub` on a error `403 Forbidden`

```
RewriteRule ^sub/.*$ - [F]
```